# Cannot find symbol error (calling a method)

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compareto

The error i have is

```
Error:cannot find symbol
  symbol:  variable compareTo
  location:variable tim of type Time
```

The code where the error happens is

```
public String difference(Time tim)
{
      if(tim.compareTo==1)
{
      tim.minute = 0;
}
      //other code
}
```

and my `compareTo` is

```
public int compareTo(Object other)
{
    if (((Time)other).getHour()<hour)
    {
     return 1;
    }
 //and other code that repeat for return -1 and 0
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax for calling the `compareTo` method is wrong.  Without parentheses `()`, Java interprets it as a class variable.  Try

```
if (compareTo(tim) == 1)
```